# Lua any library to input and move with cursor?

Tags: lua

I am thinking how to make a "memory" affect in lua.
The point is, when I use io.read, i found out that left arrow will become ^[[D, but, I what to do things like move the curser, how to make that?
Many thanks!

PS. Now, readline may works.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just do this in the commandline. You probably want to use a game engine that supports Lua. A good example might be [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/).

Comment: LÖVE dosen't work for me, thanks, I will remove my function in my code.